# Regex, allow characters and digits, but allow up to 7 digits only

Tags: regex, validation

I would very much appreciate a bit of help with the following regex riddle.
I need regex statement that would validate against the following rules:
    The input can contain letters, special characters and digits.
    The input can't start with "0",
    The input Can have up to 7 digits

Examples of valid input:

> ```
> aa1234aa2.(less than 7 digits)
> asd234566 (less than 7 digits)
> ```

Examples of invalid input:

> ```
> 0asdfd92 (starts with 0)
> asd12312311 (more than 7 digits)
> ```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
 ^\D[0-9]{0,7}$,
```

validates against d0000000, but the input may be d0d0dddd1234d

The part can't start with 0 can be removed from the requirement if it complicates a lot. The most important is to have "Can have up to 7 digits" part.

Regards,
Oleg

Comment: So even `abc1` is a valid input for you?

Comment: yes, abc1 is a valid input

Comment: But this contradicts requirement n.1 `Can't start with "0", allow letters or special characters.` I read this as "can't allow letters at all"

Comment: Maybe `^[1-9A-Za-z][a-zA-Z\d]{6}$` can you post some sample strings?

Comment: Oh, your whole string can only have 7 numbers, and any number of alpha characters. Is that correct? If that is the case I'd strip all non numbers then run a regex that first character isn't `0` and the total number is less than 7. Depending on language or platform approaches would vary.. In PHP you could first use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php to confirm all characters are alphanumerical.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try this `^[^0].{0,6}$`

Comment: Why would you need to do it with one long, unreadable, unmaintainable regular expression. Why not test each rule separately?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need!

```
Attempt 1: ^[1-9]\d{0,6}$
Attempt 2: ^[^0][\d\w]{0,6}$
Attempt 3: ^[^0].{0,6}$
Attempt 4: ^([\D]*\d){0,7}[\D]*$
Attempt 5: ^([\D]*[1-9]){0,7}[\D]*$|^[^0]\d{0,6}$
Attempt 6: ^([\D]*[1-9]){1,7}[\D]*$|^[^0]\d{1,6}$ <- this should work
```

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/wN9vN5/6)

Comment: Thanks but the string could start with something different than a number

Comment: `Can't start with "0", allow letters or special characters.` Could you clarify the rules please?

Comment: Clever solution! +1

Comment: That won't match `50000000` but will incorrectly match `foobar`

Comment: This is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirements correctly, this will work:

```
^(?=[^0])(\D*\d){0,7}\D*$
```

That will allow any string that does not start with a zero and has 7 or fewer digits. Any other characters are allowed in any quantity.

**Explanation**

The first part `(?=[^0])` is an assertion that checks to make sure the string does not start with zero. The rest matches any number of non-digits followed by a digit, up to 7 times. Then any number of non-digits before the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Perl (it looks like Perl regular expressions):

1. Check for leading zero: `if (subst($pass, 0, 1) eq '0') { fail }`
2. Check for no more than seven digits: `if (($pass =~ tr /0-9/0-9/) > 7) { fail }`

I'm generally against trying to cram everything into a single regular expression, especially when there are other tools available to do the job.  In this case, the `tr` will not be executed if there is a leading zero, and a leading zero is easy to spot in the beginning of a string.

Doing it this way, it's easy to add further restrictions independently of the others. For example, "there may be more than 7 digits if they are all separated by other types of characters" (a regex for this one, probably).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^0](?:\D*\d){1,7}\D*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH0sQ0/2)

This will perform following validations:

1. Must start with non-zero
2. Has 1 to 7 digits after first char

Answer (score 0):

Verbose, but does the trick.

`(^[1-9][^\d]*([\d]?[^\d]*){0,6}$|^[^\d]+([\d]?[^\d]*){0,7}$)`

I found it easier to split the RegEx into two cases: when the string starts with a digit, and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?:\D+(?:\d?\D*){0,7})|(?:[1-9]\D*(?:\d?\D*){0,6}))$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/sT4jH2/1)